# Translating A Function and Moving Integrals Bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Recently I came across an interesting calculus question (at least for me).
It goes as follows:

It is known that $\int_0^4f(x) dx=6.$ The value of $\int_{3}^{7}\big(\,f(x-3)+2\big)dx$ is ?
The correct answer is $14$.

This seems like quite a logical conclusion. The function is being shifted to the right 3 units, so the bounds can be increased by 3 to obtain the same area. However, taking into account functions with discontinuities or other irregularities, is there potential for this equation to not hold? In other words: does doing this to an integral's bounds work with every single function known to mankind? Probably a stupid question but hey, it's been bugging me.

Comment: Just change variables.  Letting $z=x-3$ we get $\int_3^7f(x-3)\,dx = \int_0^4f(z)\,dz=6$  That is, these two integrals are literally the same.  If you are assured the latter exists (and equals $6$) then you know the same about the former.

Comment: Do you already know the change of variable formula?

Comment: @user251257 I think so. Is it the one where you make u=something then take its derivative, subsequently rearranging for dx then substituting back in.

Comment: @lulu ah I see. So if the original integral exists then we know the translated integral also exists.

Comment: Yes.  the integrals coincide.  Assuming you are looking at Riemann integrals, the associated Riemann sums are exactly the same.

Comment: @lulu Hmm, so lets say for the sake of it that I wasn't looking at a Riemann integral. Would this not hold in some special cases?

Comment: I can't think of any notion of integration in which this substitution would not hold.  Certainly it holds in every standard notion.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{3}^{7}\left(\ f(x-3)+2\right)dx
=\int_{3}^{7}f(x-3)dx+\int_{3}^{7}2dx=\int_{3}^{7}f(x-3)d(x-3)+2\int_{3}^{7}dx
=\int_{3-3}^{7-3}f(u)du+2\cdot (7-3)=\int_{0}^{4}f(u)du+8=6+8=14.$$